# The location of AWS EC2 jcloud endpoint in WSO2 Private PaaS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wso2, paas, wso2-stratos

Does anyone has any idea as to where the endpoint address of AWS EC2 IaaS service is stored in the WSO2 Private PaaS install package?

The question seems strange, normally we do not set this information because the world is using the "Same" AWS EC2 service, and the WSO2 Private PaaS knows endpoint address and can do it automatically for us.

Yet in order to conform with the Chinese government's internet censure, Amazon has to logically totally segregate the AWS EC2 service provided within China mainland.

So, you are actually using a totally "different" AWS EC2 service in China; you had to replace the "global" service endpoint with that of the china.

please advise

thanks

Comment: It's actually Apache JClouds which "knows" the EC2 endpoint in Stratos. So there's a chance that these details can be passed as an EC2 emulator service. I'm not sure if Stratos supports using an EC2 emulator service options though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the following system property: aws-ec2.endpoint
https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/aws-ec2/